# Stream using VLC on WinForms is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, vlc, libvlc, vlc.dotnet

Im using VS2017, C#, and WinForms to make a desktop application. I installed the VLC.DotNet library through NuGet, and trying to play a local video and works perfectly. Nevertheless, when I try to set the media as a url to stream it in this way:

```
vlcControl1.SetMedia(new Uri("https://inliveserver.com:2000/l/?listen.8572.m3u8"));
```

and then I play it, nothing happens. Is this the right way to do it? I saw this method in several tutorials and it appears to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As I found no solution in the whole web, I read a comment that opened my mind "m3u8 are just text files with the actual path to the file". So I downloaded that file, and I saw another m3u8, I used that in the VLC plugin and worked! So the issue was a concatenation of playlist. Even if in the standalone VLC application this works, in the C# component is not allowed.

TL/DR: It was a playlist inside a playlist, VLC component apparently has issues with that.